# Android studio is not creating the views ids immediately after declaring it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-databinding

Before updating my android studio it was running great. After the update I am facing a problem. Using databinding facility when I declare the id of any view in my layout, android studio is not showing any suggestion of that id in java file until I rebuild the project. But previous version of android studio it showed the id suggestion immediately without make, clean or rebuild project. My android studio's current version is 3.1.2. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try Invalidating cache.
[image]

Hope this fix the issue.

Comment: I do this more then 100 times in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me:

***You can also check if Power Save Mode on File menu is disabled.***

Another solution is this:

```
Project Settings [name]
Inspections - ensure that Android and Android Lint is checked, or alternatively just set it back to default using the dropdown box at the top.

IDE Settings
Editor -> Code Completion - ensure the Autopopup code completion is checked (and check the rest of the settings based on your preference.
```